# How to display QML in the center with QQuickWidget inside QTabWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I'm trying to display custom listView with QQuickWidget.
Since I need two listView: one for a search result, one for a queue,
I used QTabWidget to switch between those two QQuickWidget.

I haven't finished making that listView (Because I'm a beginner at this)
so I improvised my QML to test if it works as I typed above.
When I run my app, QML that is inside QTabWidget is shown unexpectedly.

It should display a yellow rectangle and text like the QQuickWidget below, but it displays text aligned at the top left corner, without a yellow rectangle.

When the application is executed

[image]

[Things I've tried]
I assumed this is because I put QQuickWidget inside QWidget at each Tab, so I promoted those QWidget as custom page that has QQuickWidget but nothing has changed.

**main.py**

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtQuickWidgets import QQuickWidget
from myresulttab import myResultTab
from myqueuetab import myQueueTab

#loading UI file
form_class = uic.loadUiType("mainWindowUI.ui")[0]

class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class) :

    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.testQuickWidget.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("resultTabQml.qml"))


if __name__ == "__main__" :

    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    myWindow = WindowClass() 
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**mainWindowUI.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>555</width>
    <height>821</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="font">
   <font>
    <family>NanumGothic</family>
    <pointsize>10</pointsize>
    <weight>50</weight>
    <italic>false</italic>
    <bold>false</bold>
   </font>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true"/>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout" rowstretch="50,5,45,0" columnstretch="70,0">
    <property name="verticalSpacing">
     <number>15</number>
    </property>
    <item row="2" column="0" colspan="2">
     <widget class="QQuickWidget" name="testQuickWidget">
      <property name="resizeMode">
       <enum>QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0" colspan="2">
     <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="elideMode">
       <enum>Qt::ElideNone</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="myResultTab" name="resultTab">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>NanumGothic</family>
         <pointsize>10</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <italic>false</italic>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>검색창</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
      <widget class="myQueueTab" name="queueTab">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>QUEUE</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="console">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Minimum">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>NanumGothic</family>
        <pointsize>10</pointsize>
        <weight>50</weight>
        <italic>false</italic>
        <bold>false</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="toolTip">
       <string extracomment="프로그램이 당신에게 보내는 편지입니다. 다정하게 대해주세요 :)"/>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>resultTabQML.qml should be displayed like this!</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>555</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menu_F">
    <property name="title">
     <string>파일(&amp;F)</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menu_E">
    <property name="title">
     <string>편집(&amp;E)</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menu_F"/>
   <addaction name="menu_E"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QQuickWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header location="global">QtQuickWidgets/QQuickWidget</header>
  </customwidget>
  <customwidget>
   <class>myResultTab</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>myresulttab.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
  <customwidget>
   <class>myQueueTab</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>myqueuetab.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
 <slots>
  <slot>inquireDataBtnPressed()</slot>
  <slot>insertDataBtnPressed()</slot>
  <slot>deleteDataBtnPressed()</slot>
  <slot>updateDataBtnPressed()</slot>
  <slot>getDataFromApiBtnPressed()</slot>
 </slots>
</ui>
```

**myResultTab.py**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtQuickWidgets import QQuickWidget

class myResultTab(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        resultQuickWidget = QQuickWidget(QUrl.fromLocalFile("resultTabQml.qml"))
        layout.addWidget(resultQuickWidget)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

**myQueueTab.py**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtQuickWidgets import QQuickWidget

class myQueueTab(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        queueQuickWidget = QQuickWidget(QUrl.fromLocalFile("queueTabQml.qml"))
        layout.addWidget(queueQuickWidget)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

**resultTabQml.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Item{
    Rectangle{
        id:rect1
        color:"yellow"
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text {
            id: sampleText1
            text: qsTr("sampleText1")
            font.family: "Arial"
            font.pointSize: 50
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.fill: parent
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
    }

}
/*##^##
Designer {
    D{i:0;autoSize:true;height:480;width:640}
}
##^##*/
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: I'm sorry but you want me to provide code so that you can reproduce the error? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Exactly, I need all the code needed to reproduce the problem, so I can analyze where the problem is and probably give you a solution. My recommendation is that you make a copy of your project and remove the unnecessary code: regex, databases, etc., but that even your code is workable, and then edit your question and add all the .qml, .ui and .py that result from the above.

Comment: I've added ,ui file and removed unnecessary codes. Check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the [`ResizeMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html#resizeMode-prop) property to `SizeRootObjectToView` so that the root expands based on the size of QQuickWidget:

```
import os

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtQuickWidgets import QQuickWidget

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class myResultTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "resultTabQml.qml")
        resultQuickWidget = QQuickWidget(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
        resultQuickWidget.setResizeMode(QQuickWidget.SizeRootObjectToView)
        layout.addWidget(resultQuickWidget)
```

[image]

If you do not set it then the resizeMode uses the default `SizeViewToRootObject` that the item will not take into account the size of the view so that the item will have size 0x0 and consequently the yellow rectangle will also be that same size, and the text will be centered on the position (0, 0) which is shown in the image provided by the OP.